# EF provider for Oracle

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'd like to know if there are any good EF providers for Oracle out there, and more specifically what experiences people have had with them. We're looking for a provider that is either free or paid for, but I'm struggling a bit with finding any real opinions on what the different frameworks are like to work with in a production environment.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***
I should clarify that we are using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Have you looked at http://oracleef.codeplex.com/ or http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider?

Comment: Not yet, will give it a look. Thanks Gabe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Devart](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) has a decent offer in this domain

Comment: Thank you vc, I'll give it a look. I'll leave your answer unaccepted for a bit longer to see if I get some more suggestions.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm definitely not holding the ultimate truth on that topic or any other topic. Someone might give a better answer and I'll be glad to learn something.

Comment: Just to let you know, we went with Devart and it worked out well. Thanks again vc 74!

Comment: I've been using Devart for a year now. I'll advice against making standard EF models and instead creating Devart EF models. This uses Devart's own EF designer. The reason I say this is that Oracle has many quirks that SQL Server doesn't have so Microsoft's EF doesn't handles them. Example: with Devart you can easily set which columns are Identity (you have to manually edit XML to do this without Devart's EF designer). Devart also maps Number(1) columns to bool as Oracle doesn't have native booleans like SQL Server. Expect some bugs here and there in Devart but at least they fix them quick.

Answer (score 3):

Some light... Oracle has released a beta version of EF.  Download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html